# Does lower the temperature always mean more stable structure and larger density?

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals

In solid states, the lower temperature meant more stable structure and transition fro bcc(packing fraction 0.74) fcc(packing fraction 0.74) to hcp(packing fraction 0.68).

1.a. Does this mean atom, such as Fe, at bcc had larger lattice parameter and lower density than Fe at fcc (At same temperature and pressure)?

1.b. Fe went through three different states (bcc-fcc-bcc) at very high temperature to standard temperature and pressure, but iron expand in summer(a bit of high temperature). Does this mean Fe would expand(bcc-fcc) then shrink(fcc-bcc) with the increase of temperature?

2.a. Does lower the temperature always mean more stable structure? However, I heard people saying that Tin(Sn) would become powder like dust when at low temperature, a clear contradiction to the ideal of "stable".

2.b. A side question: Though water was not metal, it also become more organized and thus expand during the transition from liquid to solid. Has the ice become more stable or less stable?

Comment: There are several questions here. Please pose only one question per post.

Comment: Fcc and hcp have the same packing density...

Comment: @JonCuster But bcc and fcc wasn't, the transition of fe went through fcc in gamma phase. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allotropes_of_iron#Gamma_iron_(%CE%B3-Fe)  )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iron is a particularly bad crystal to investigate phase stability vs temperature. The reason is the large influence of magnetic energy on the Gibbs free energy. The place to see this is in Dinsdale's [compilation of elemental free energies](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/036459169190030N).

So there are several interesting things to see. First, without the magnetic contributions, the stable crystal structure at room temperature would actually be hcp, transitioning to fcc, then to bcc as the temperature increases. This is a not uncommon series of transitions for various elements.

Further, Dinsdale has a plot of the P-T phase diagram, where one sees that as the pressure is increased into the GPa range the bcc phase is no longer stable. Then hcp is actually stable at room temperature and fcc is stable at higher temperatures. (To some extent this is reasonable because of the higher packing fraction of (hcp, fcc) vs bcc.

(Tin going to 'powder' has more to do with the accumulated stresses in a solid-solid phase transition. Don't confuse that with actual phase stability.)